# Why python is reading L=L*3 instead of L*=3 for list?

Tags: python

There is the code given below:

```
L=[5,10,15,20]
print(L*=3)
```

We know that the above code's result will be `[5,10,15,20,5,10,15,20,5,10,15,20]`. But instead of that, it is showing 'invalid syntax' error in IDLE Python(latest version).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79jRU.png)

Even I tried in VS Code(latest version). But it still showing error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSyY0.jpg)

Can anyone tell why it is not accepting it? Is it bug or software problem?

Comment: How do you know that it will result in `[5,10,15,20,5,10,15,20,5,10,15,20]`? You are passing an assignment expression to a print function. That is invalid sintax... Maybe you want `print(L*3)`?

Comment: Whatever you provide to a function like `print(...)` must be an expression. `L*=3` is not an expression, but a statement.

Comment: Please copy-paste the error message to the wuestion, don't only attach images.

Comment: As per [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) on [meta] -- upload error messages **as text**.

Comment: Ohk, it means I have to read python more thoroughly

Comment: `print(L*=3)` works in some other programming languages (such as C, C++, C#, Java and JavaScript), but not in Python.

Comment: If you really need it in Python 3.8+, do this: `print(L:=L*3)`.

Comment: Sorry, since I am a newbie, I didn't know about these things. Now I will remember it.

Answer (score 1):

Assignment is a statement, not an expression. `L*=3` *on it's own* is valid, but it isn't a valid argument to `print`.